# Alert Dialog hidden behind soft-keyboard android

Tags: android

This is my custom alert dialog code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/inset_background_dialog"
            android:padding="@dimen/dialog_elements_margin">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_add_address_title_addnewaddress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="@string/add_new_address_title_addnewaddress"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_close_dialogue_addnewaddress"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dialog_close_button"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_close_button"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_unchecked_black"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_address_title_addnewaddress"
                style="@style/roundedEditText"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text_add_address_title_addnewaddress"
                android:hint="@string/address_title_hint_addnewaddress"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_mobile_number_addnewaddress"
                style="@style/roundedEditText"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edit_address_title_addnewaddress"
                android:hint="@string/mobile_number_hint_addnewaddress"
                android:inputType="number"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_apartment_no_addnewaddress"
                style="@style/roundedEditText"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edit_mobile_number_addnewaddress"
                android:hint="@string/house_no_hint_addnewaddress"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_landmark_addnewaddress"
                style="@style/roundedEditText"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edit_apartment_no_addnewaddress"
                android:hint="@string/landmark_hint_addnewaddress"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_location_addnewaddress"
                style="@style/roundedEditText"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edit_landmark_addnewaddress"
                android:hint="@string/address_hint_addnewaddress"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/save_address_addnewaddress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_elements_height"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edit_location_addnewaddress"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dialog_elements_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/add_button_back_about_product"
                android:text="@string/save_address_button_addnewaddress"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/tabSelectedTextColor"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is, edit-text fields at the bottom are hidden behind the soft keyboard. I tried updating the android manifest to android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" within the particular activity yet no luck. Any solution for this?

Comment: you can remove main RelativeLayout use only scrollview then at least user can move up the screen.

Comment: nope, that dint work.

Comment: will it ok, if you change the position of your alert dialog ? if yes then set it to top.

Comment: even though i made the gravity as TOP, the button is hidden behind the keyboard, i guess a better solution would be to make the layout scrollable which i'm not able to achieve for now.

Comment: try this scrollview as i am posting the code in  answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
    <EditView />
    <Button />
</LinearLayout>
```

set your UI inside the LinearLayout and try.